# Specify datatype in CREATE TABLE AS statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, type-conversion

I am creating a table `dummy2` using the values in another table `dummy`. This is my syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy2 AS SELECT
t1.zid AS orig_id,
t2.zid AS dest_id,
ABS(RANDOM()*(45-2)-45) AS dist
FROM dummy t1, dummy t2;
```

The attribute `zid` in `dummy` is stored as `DOUBLE PRECISION`. However, in the new table I would like to change its data-type to say, `INTEGER`. How can I achieve this? My initial thoughts were this (very similar to the way we declare the data-type when creating a table using the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy2 AS SELECT
t1.zid AS orig_id INTEGER,
t2.zid AS dest_id INTEGER,
ABS(RANDOM()*(45-2)-45) AS dist
FROM dummy t1, dummy t2;
```

But it fails to execute. Can anyone help me out with this? Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Did you try explicitly CASTing or CONVERTing the zid column to INTEGER, in the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dummy2 AS SELECT
cast(t1.zid as integer) AS orig_id,
cast(t2.zid as integer) AS dest_id,
ABS(RANDOM()*(45-2)-45) AS dist
FROM dummy t1, dummy t2;
```

Comment: can we do cast null as integer and expect it to be integer

Comment: If all values are null what does the column data type turn out to be?